# Google Chrome Search results shows black boxes with text?

Tags: google-chrome

I searched for the term "I like turtles".
Notice the search results has some distracting black box text labels.
This must be a very recent change, as I've never seen that before.
What are they and how can it be disabled? Thanks.

[image: BLACK_LABELS]

**EDIT**

As suggested, it's related to the Dark theme: On
Changing it to Off, still shows the very light box labels.
I assume there no way to totally suppress the labels because some sites have it while others do not. **Version 95.0.4638.69 (Official Build) (64-bit)**

[image: dark theme off]

Comment: That is likely a by product of the dark theme. Google Chrome on my machine (light theme) shows normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure this is dark / light theme related and possibly Windows theme.

I am using Google Chrome  Version 95.0.4638.69 (Official Build) (64-bit) and I do not see the extra shading.

I think this is a function of the Chrome build and I do not see any way within Chrome to prevent this.  A future update may change things.

[image: Google Chrome appearance]